# Setting a memory quota for Microsoft Terminal Server connection

Tags: group-policy, terminal-server, memory, quota

Is there a way to 'throttle down' the amount of memory accessible to a given user (or all users) on a terminal server session?

Note, this is just to debug an in-house app without physically going into our server and taking out RAM, not something we'd actually do to our employees.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is what your looking for: Windows System Resource Manager
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732553.aspx